# Magento 1.9.1 sending multiple emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

I have my store setup and ready to work with it. When I'm going to make a test order, I noticed that Magento is sending the confirmation email multiple times, doesn´t stop sending. I'm receiving the emails two by two.

And I've noticed that an exception is being thrown in `exception.log`:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (message_id='3')' at line 1, query was: UPDATE `core_email_queue` SET  WHERE (message_id='3')' in /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_em...', Array)
#4 /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_em...', Array)
#5 /home/newolders/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(635): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `core_em...', Array)
#6 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('core_email_queu...', Array, 'message_id='3'')
#7 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))
#8 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(244): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#10 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#12 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /home/newolders/public_html/store/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#15 /home/newolders/public_html/store/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#16 {main}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: which magento version,you have using?

Comment: He answered in title. This feature appeared only in 1.9.1.x

Comment: YEAH thats nice! I have the same problem. And while sending my log output as an answer (because there is not enougth space in a comment) was not right (mentioned by some mod) but editing the question and add the log was also rejected by anyone. so wtf. is wrong with you?!

again the log displayed that the processedAt-Property was filled correctly but the update-query was build wrong. sry but i cannot show you the log because of some really creepy people around here. -,- nuff said

Comment: @Elias Soares: Do you have AOE_Scheduler extension running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you found the solution in the mean time, but I recently came into the same problem on a client's server.

What happened was indeed the same, the cron job **core_email_queue_send_all** was sending the same emails multiple times and each time the same exception you found was added into the exception log.

The cron job was sending the same emails multiple times because the `processed_at` field did not get saved in the `core_email_queue` table for the corresponding messages.

I've added some logs into the code and looked into how the query for saving the `core_email_queue` message was built, and why it was missing the SET part of it (which should have contained the columns to be updated):

```
UPDATE `core_email_queue` SET  WHERE (message_id='3')'
```

In Magento, before building the database queries, the columns used in the query get checked against the column descriptions for the respective table inside the `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForTable` method by calling:

```
$fields = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->describeTable($table);
```

In order not to execute the DESCRIBE query each time, Magento caches the DDL info for the tables. Inside the `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::describeTable` method the cache is first checked:

```
public function describeTable($tableName, $schemaName = null)
{
    $cacheKey = $this->_getTableName($tableName, $schemaName);
    $ddl = $this->loadDdlCache($cacheKey, self::DDL_DESCRIBE);
    if ($ddl === false) {
        $ddl = array_map(
            array(
                $this,
                'decorateTableInfo'
            ),
            parent::describeTable($tableName, $schemaName)
        );
        /**
        * Remove bug in some MySQL versions, when int-column without default value is described as:
        * having default empty string value
        */
        $affected = array('tinyint', 'smallint', 'mediumint', 'int', 'bigint');
        foreach ($ddl as $key => $columnData) {
            if (($columnData['DEFAULT'] === '') && (array_search($columnData['DATA_TYPE'], $affected) !== FALSE)) {
                $ddl[$key]['DEFAULT'] = null;
            }
        }
        $this->saveDdlCache($cacheKey, self::DDL_DESCRIBE, $ddl);
    }

    return $ddl;
}
```

I found that the columns received from the cache for the `core_email_queue` table, were not the ones expected, instead sometimes they were: `data`, `lifetime`, `expire` and `priority`.

This pointed to a cache problem and I found that `Zend_Cache_Core` was saving data into the DDL cache files, sometimes by calling `Zend_Cache_Backend_File::save()` directly and sometimes by calling `Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels::save()`.

The two levels cache from Zend uses the `_prepareData` method to build a serialized array to store the data and metadata information:

```
private function _prepareData($data, $lifetime, $priority)
{
    $lt = $lifetime;
    if ($lt === null) {
        $lt = 9999999999;
    }
    return serialize(array(
        'data' => $data,
        'lifetime' => $lifetime,
        'expire' => time() + $lt,
        'priority' => $priority
    ));
}
```

Finally, the issue was that the cron (which sent the emails) was called from the command line. Comparing a request from the browser with a command line request, I found that `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::getBackendOptions` was returning different options. This server was set up to use APC cache, however when the cron was running `ini_get(‘apc.enabled’)` was false.

On this server there were 2 php configuration files **fpm/php.ini** where **apc.enabled** was **1**, and **cli/php.ini** where **apc.enabled** was **0**.
The Magento instance that was run from the command line was not able, thus, to use the APC cache, so it did not use a two-level cache, which led to it not knowing how to correctly read the data from the cache files.

The fpm Magento instance used APC and the two level cache and was saving DDL data into the **var/cache** folder enclosed in an array with the `data`, `lifetime`, `expire` and `priority` keys.
When the cron ran and read the DDL cache file, it used the data found there and basically considered for each table, that the columns are `data`, `lifetime`, `expire` and `priority`.

Changing **apc.enabled** to **1** in the **cli/php.ini** configuration file did the trick and solved the issue.

If you are interested on reading more about how I debugged this issue you can have a look over the more detailed explication I wrote for a blog post: http://ayg.ro/magento-cron-twolevel-cache-issue-pdoexception-sqlstate-42s22-and-sqlstate-42000

Comment: I've solved this in another way that I don't remind anymore. BUT, Your solution is very well explained and make sense to me, so I'll mark as right answer, since this may help many people with similar issue!

Answer (score 4):

This issue must be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table. If this is your issue, I send you a fix.

The new Magento Email Queue system manages these two tables: **core_email_queue** and **core_email_queue_recipients**. The former one handles the email Messages, and the later one, the Recipients of these messages.

The **core_email_queue** table is cleaned out as emails on the Magento Email Queue are sent. This cleaning is performed by a cron tab job called *core_email_queue_clean_up*, that's defined inside the *app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xm*l config file. The code that performs the cleaning is defined on the *removeSentMessages* function in the *Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue* class:

```
/**
 * Remove already sent messages
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue
 */
public function removeSentMessages()
{
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable(), 'processed_at IS NOT NULL');
    return $this;
}
```

The above code is executed once a day by the cron task.

But it happens that the **core_email_queue_recipients** table (the one that holds email Recipients, and that is linked to the **core_email_queue** table by the *message_id* field ), is not cleaned together with the **core_email_queue** table (the one that holds email Messages), leaving orphan records inside that Recipients table when then Message table is cleaned out.

The issue described here arises when the **core_email_queue** table (Messages) is reset and the autoincrement *message_id* field on this table is reinitiated to 1.

Because the **core_email_queue_recipients** table (Recipients) has not been cleaned accordingly, when new emails are added to the Magento Email Queue, new records are created on the **core_email_queue** table (with *message_id* starting again from 1), and at the same time new records are created on the **core_email_queue_recipients** table with these same ids (starting again from 1).

The problem is that these ids may already exist on the Recipients table as orphans records (due to previous email messages). These new mesages ids then get repeated inside the **core_email_queue_recipients** table. In the end, different email Messages are linked to their corresponding Recipients by the *message_id*, but they get also wrongly linked to previous recepients that were assigned the same *message_id* from previous emails.

Thus, when recipients are searched to send a given message, besides the appropriate recipient, other wrong recipients may arise.

Fortunately the fix for this issue is easy to perform.

All that's needed is cleaning all repeated messages ids on the **core_email_queue_recipients** table, and making sure that when a Message is deleted on the **core_email_queue** table, at the same time its corresponding Recipients get deleted on the **core_email_queue_recipients** table.

The best way to achieve this is to create a foreign key that links these records and deletes them on cascade (but you need to make some cleaning before you can do that).

This is the procedure to fix the issue:

1) Execute the follwoing two SQL queries to clean the **core_email_queue_recipients** table from orphan records and repeated messages ids:

```
DELETE FROM core_email_queue_recipients WHERE message_id NOT IN (SELECT message_id FROM core_email_queue);
DELETE FROM core_email_queue_recipients WHERE recipient_id < (SELECT recipient_id FROM (SELECT recipient_id FROM core_email_queue_recipients ORDER BY message_id ASC, recipient_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS r);
```

The first query deletes orphan records, and the second one deletes old records that are no longer valid.

2) Create a foreign key on the **core_email_queue_recipients** table to delete Recipients records on cascade. The SQL query to create this foreign key is:

```
ALTER TABLE core_email_queue_recipients ADD FOREIGN KEY(message_id) REFERENCES core_email_queue(message_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

By using this new foreign key, no orphan records will be left on the **core_email_queue_recipients** table when cleaning the **core_email_queue** table, and no duplicated messages to wrong recipients will be sent in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see your query

```
UPDATE `core_email_queue` SET  WHERE (message_id='3')'
```

doesn't have what to set. I think in here magento trying to set some status which sense is 'letter already sent'. I'm not sure, maybe update field `processed_at`

**upd.1**

It looks like idea was right. Before save we have this (Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(244)):

```
$message->setProcessedAt(Varien_Date::formatDate(true));
```

Could you after this

```
Mage::log(Varien_Date::formatDate(true));
Mage::log($message->getData());
```

And show us result.

**upd.2**

I didn't reproduce the described issue. I have

> Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
>
> nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
>
> PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
>
> MySQL server version 5.6.19
>
> Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

What is your config?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find where fix it in the magento code... :/

Comment: I'm watching at it.. Could you include in your first post few steps how to enable this feature to let appear some rows in this table? Or show us this table

Comment: Waiting for details from you

Comment: Just the fresh install of Magento 1.9.1 and the error occours.
Make an example order, and the problem will occours when it tries to send the order confirmation mail.

Comment: I will run this test as soon as possible and tell you the result. ;)

Comment: as mentioned in comment above: processedAt was set correctly.
i tried to dig deeper and found that **sometimes**:
$this->_getWriteAdapter()->describeTable($table); results in wrong table description. It returns not the columns of email_queue. it returns columns like this: data, lifetime, expire, priority

And sometimes the right columns:
message_id, entity_id, entity_type, message_body, ..., processed_at